# Xampp/Mac - make a JPEG file accessible via HTTP

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a virtual directory set up:

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/branding">
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

with an alias defined:

```
Alias /branding "/Applications/XAMPP/branding"
```

i put a jpeg file in that folder and trying to access it via:

```
http://127.0.0.1/branding/image.jpeg
```

I am getting an authentication error:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

127.0.0.1
Tue Nov 13 12:15:14 2012
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

I restarted the web server after making my changes.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the entire vhost directive please? Perhaps with the domain changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the file have permissions that are visible to the user that Apache is running as?

If you do an "ls -lah", what is your output?

Comment: great :-) you can also change the User directive to determine which user apache will run as (however, I'd just stick to file permissions if I were you)